# Django ORM: exclude does not return expected result

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm

**Django 1.11.4**

I'd like to select only frames with lost items.
If an item is lost, lost_day is not empty.

The problem: I can't understand what is going on in case of **"Wrong result"**. I would say, it should return the same result as the **"Correct result"**. Could you help me realize what is wrong with it?

**Wrong result**

```
>>> Frame.objects.all().exclude(item__lost_day__isnull=True)
    <QuerySet [<Frame: 3>]>
```

**Correct result:**

```
>>> Frame.objects.all().filter(item__lost_day__isnull=False)
    <QuerySet [<Frame: 1>, <Frame: 3>]>
```

**Self-checking**

```
>>> a = Item.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> a.lost_day
datetime.date(1997, 1, 1)
>>> a.lost_day is None
False

>>> b = Item.objects.get(pk=2)
>>> b.lost_day
datetime.date(1997, 2, 2)
>>> b.lost_day is None
False
```

**models.py**

```
class Frame(models.Model):
    pass

class Item(models.Model):
    frame = models.ForeignKey(Frame,
                          blank=False,
                          on_delete=models.PROTECT,
                          verbose_name=_("frame"))
    lost_day = models.DateField(auto_now=False,
                                auto_now_add=False,
                                blank=True,
                                null=True,
                                verbose_name=_("lost"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you show:

```
Frame.objects.filter(pk=1).values('item__lost_day')
```

looks like you have multi reference with empty and not `lost_day`, so we have

```
[{'item__lost_day': None},
 {'item__lost_day': datetime.date(1997, 1, 1)},
 {'item__lost_day': None}]
```

when you query `Frame.objects.exclude(item__lost_day__isnull=True)` then djanqo get all `frames` that not have `item__lost_day__isnull` and this is frame `pk=3` it has null values, but not `frame <1>`

and when you `Frame.objects.filter(item__lost_day__isnull=False)` then django find all `frames` with not null `lost_day` and they are 1 and 3 == all right.

The most trouble in your research is you change condition(null, not_null) and method(filter, exclude) **all together**.

Comment: The result will be: <QuerySet [{'item__lost_day': datetime.date(1997, 2, 2)}]>

Comment: sorry i was wrong logic, need check for `pk=1`, try it and hope it help

Comment: The result is: Frame.objects.filter(pk=1).values('item__lost_day')
<QuerySet [{'item__lost_day': None}, {'item__lost_day': datetime.date(1997, 1, 1)}, {'item__lost_day': None}]>
 Well, really multiple reference with None value. I still can't grab the idea. Could you explain, what is going on here?